# Rails]Using Markdown Markup Language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, markup

In my rails application, people are supposed to submit "posts." However, in the default scaffolding, there are some problems in the text input: not allowed HTML code, changing the line doesn't work, etc. From what I've learned, I need to use a markdown-markup language to solve this issue. Is there a guide for me to follow to apply such language to solve my problem?

UPDATE: Here are my problems.

1) Every sentence is combined into one line even if I put a line space.

```
first line
second line
```

becomes

`first line second line`

2) I can't make text bold, italicized, or hyperlink. Like in stackoverflow, user should easily put `<b>` and make bold text, `**` to make italicized, etc. And URL address should automatically be translated to href link.

To do these, I thought I had to use *markdown* library. I could be mistaken, so I needed someone to guide me through. [Railscasts on Markdown](http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet?view=asciicast)

Comment: Extremely unclear question. Do you want to solve the problem of people not being able to insert HTML or line breaks (why not?!?!) or do you want to specifically use Markdown? Neither is *"required"*.

Comment: @deceze, sorry about that. Check my update if you could.

Comment: Well, yes, new lines in HTML have no meaning. You need to replace line breaks with `<br>` to preserve them in HTML. To *automatically* highlight links, you need to look for links in the text and wrap them in appropriate `<a>` tags. Finally, if you're not *filtering* HTML tags, they should still be in there. It all depends on what you're doing. Markdown is something entirely different, a special markup language that enables you to do the above while being easier to write than HTML. It depends on what you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. If you post it as an answer instead of comment, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: If that's all you needed... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, new lines in HTML have no meaning. You need to replace line breaks with `<br>` to preserve them in HTML. To *automatically* highlight links, you need to look for links in the text and wrap them in appropriate `<a>` tags. Finally, if you're not *filtering* HTML tags, they should still be in there. It all depends on what you're doing. Markdown is something entirely different, a special markup language that enables you to do the above while being easier to write than HTML. It depends on what you want to use.